# Evaluating covariance terms for variance of residual in simple linear regression

Tags: regression, self-study, variance, covariance, residuals

I am trying to work through calculating the variance of a residual for simple linear regression not using vectors or matrices. I am having trouble with calculating two different covariance expressions that prevent me from getting the correct answer:
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}(y_i - \hat{y_i}) = \sigma^2 \Big(1 - \frac{1}{n} - \frac{(x_i - \bar{x})^2}{S_{xx}} \Big)
\end{align}
This is what I have done so far,
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}(y_i - \hat{y_i}) &= \operatorname{Var}(\beta_1 x_i + \beta_0 + \epsilon_i - \hat{\beta_1}x_i - \hat{\beta_0})\\
&= \operatorname{Var}(x_i(\beta_1 - \hat{\beta_1}) + (\beta_0 - \hat{\beta_0}) + \epsilon_i)
\end{align}
Since $\operatorname{Var}(X+Y+Z) = \operatorname{Var}(X) + \operatorname{Var}(Y) + \operatorname{Var}(Z) + 2\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y) + 2\operatorname{Cov}(X,Z) + 2\operatorname{Cov}(Y,Z)$, I will evaluate each term. What I have trouble with are the last two covariance expressions. For these two, unless I commit what I think are errors in the calculation, I won't arrive at the textbook answer.

For the first term, $\beta_1$ and $x_i$ are constants and $\hat{\beta_1}$ is a random variable, so 
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Var}(x_i(\beta_1 - \hat{\beta_1})) &= x_i^2 \operatorname{Var}(\hat{\beta_1})\\
&= \frac{x_i^2 \sigma^2}{S_{xx}}
\end{align*}
where $S_{xx} = \sum (x_i - \bar{x})^2$

Next, using the same reasoning,
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Var}(\beta_0 - \hat{\beta_0}) &= \operatorname{Var}(\hat{\beta_0})\\
&= \sigma^2 \Big( \frac{1}{n}+ \frac{\bar{x}^2}{S_{xx}}\Big)
\end{align*}

Third, by definition,
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Var}(\epsilon_i) = \sigma^2
\end{align*}

The fourth term is the first of the covariance ones:
\begin{align*}
2\operatorname{Cov}(x_i(\beta_1 - \hat{\beta_1}), \beta_0 - \hat{\beta_0}) &= 2x_i \operatorname{Cov}(\hat{\beta_1}, \hat{\beta_0}) \\
&= -\frac{2x_i \bar{x}\sigma^2}{S_{xx}}
\end{align*}
Now, if I stop here and sum of all the terms I've calculated so far, I will get an expression that equals the variance of $\hat{y_i}$ for a new $x_i$ value also known as a prediction interval:
\begin{align}
\sigma^2 \Big(1 + \frac{1}{n} + \frac{(x_i - \bar{x})^2}{S_{xx}}\Big)
\end{align}

Now is where I have trouble with the last 2 covariance terms:
\begin{align}
2\operatorname{Cov}(x_i (\beta_1 - \hat{\beta_1}), \epsilon_i) &= -2x_i \operatorname{Cov}(\hat{\beta_1}, \epsilon_i)\\
&= -\frac{2x_i}{S_{xx}}\operatorname{Cov}\Big(\sum(x_i - \bar{x})y_i, \epsilon_i\Big)\\
&= -\frac{2x_i}{S_{xx}}\sum (x_i - \bar{x})\operatorname{Cov}(y_i , \epsilon_i)\\
&= -\frac{2x_i}{S_{xx}}\sum (x_i - \bar{x})\sigma^2
\end{align}
I think this expression equals 0 which would not let me get the right answer. The only way is if I ignore the summation so that I get
\begin{align}
&=-\frac{2x_i(x_i - \bar{x})\sigma^2}{S_{xx}}
\end{align}
Likewise for the last term:
\begin{align}
2\operatorname{Cov}(\beta_0 - \hat{\beta_0}, \epsilon_i) &= - 2\operatorname{Cov}(\hat{\beta_0}, \epsilon_i)\\
&= -2\operatorname{Cov}(\bar{y} - \hat{\beta_1}\bar{x}, \epsilon_i)\\
&= -2\operatorname{Cov}\Big(\sum \frac{1}{n}y_i- \bar{x}\frac{\sum(x_i - \bar{x})y_i}{S_{xx}}, \epsilon_i\Big)\\
&= -2\sum \Big(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{\bar{x}(x_i - \bar{x})}{S_{xx}}\Big)\operatorname{Cov}(y_i , \epsilon_i)\\
&= -2\sum \Big(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{\bar{x}(x_i - \bar{x})}{S_{xx}}\Big)\sigma^2\\
&= -\frac{2}{n}\sum\sigma^2 + 2\sigma^2\frac{\sum (x_i - \bar{x})\bar{x}}{S_{xx}}\\
&= -2 \sigma^2 + 0
\end{align}
and the only way I get the correct answer is if this covariance term instead evaluated to $-2\sigma^2/n$.

To recap what I mean:
\begin{align}
\sigma^2 \Big(1 + \frac{1}{n} + \frac{(x_i - \bar{x})^2}{S_{xx}}\Big) \overbrace{-\frac{2x_i(x_i - \bar{x})\sigma^2}{S_{xx}}}^{\operatorname{Cov}(x_i(\beta_1 - \hat{\beta_1}), \epsilon_i)}  \underbrace{- \frac{2\sigma^2}{n}}_{\operatorname{Cov}(\beta_0 - \hat{\beta_0}, \epsilon_i)} = \sigma^2 \Big(1 - \frac{1}{n} - \frac{(x_i - \bar{x})^2}{S_{xx}} \Big)
\end{align}
but my last two covariance terms do not equal those values. Is there some glaring mistake I've done that someone could be so kind as to assist me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at it more, I think I might know where my error is. Looking at just $-2x_i\operatorname{Cov}(\hat{\beta_1}, \epsilon_i)$, I think am forgetting that $\epsilon_i$ refers to *just one* noise term for some $i$. Rewriting with a summation over $j$ makes this easier to understand:
\begin{align}
-\frac{2x_i}{S_{xx}}\operatorname{Cov}\Big(\sum_j (x_j - \bar{x})y_j, \epsilon_i\Big) &= -\frac{2x_i}{S_{xx}}\sum_j (x_j - \bar{x})\operatorname{Cov}(y_j, \epsilon_i)\\
&= -\frac{2x_i}{S_{xx}}\Big[(x_0 - \bar{x})\operatorname{Cov}(y_0, \epsilon_i)+ \ldots + (x_i - \bar{x})\operatorname{Cov}(y_i, \epsilon_i)+ \ldots + (x_n - \bar{x})\operatorname{Cov}(y_n, \epsilon_i)\Big]\\
&= -\frac{2x_i}{S_{xx}}\Big[0+ \ldots + (x_i - \bar{x})\sigma^2 + \ldots + 0\Big]\\
&= -\frac{2x_i(x_i - \bar{x})\sigma^2}{S_{xx}}
\end{align}
And this is the term that I want. Applying the same thing to the last covariance term also gets me what I want. What I did before was when I pulled out the summation, I grouped in the noise term as part of the expression.